# react native navigation separated process

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my application I have some multistep form, let's say it's process of adding new employee to company and we got steps like:

1. personal info
2. car(select or add)
3. final info

so when a user adds a new employee application redirects him to `AddEmployeeStack` when he can go through these 3 screens.

Screen 2(car) it's actually another stack - on this screen user can choose a car from the list of existing cars and can click "add" button and go to adding new car form(it's another stack)

so it looks like:

```js
export const NewEmployeeStack: FC = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="personalInfo" component={PersonalInfoScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="employeeCar" component={EmployeeCarStack} />
      <Stack.Screen name="finalInfo" component={FinalInfoScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export const EmployeeCarStack: FC = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="carsList" component={CarsListScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="addCar" component={AddCarStack} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export const AddCarStack: FC = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="carModel" component={CarModelScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="carRegistration" component={CarRegistrationScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="carSummary" component={CarSummaryScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

so when the user is on screen no 2, car he can choose a car or add new

if the user decides to add a new car then he can go through the process of adding a car after he finishes this process it's obvious that he just added this car because he wants to use it - so should be redirected just to `finalInfo` screen from the first stack

I can use `navigation.navigate("finalInfo")` but then if user clicks back button(android platforms) he's gonna be redirected to summary screen from `AddCarStack`

I can also use `navigation.goBack()` from `EmployeeCarStack` level and then `navigation.navigate("finalInfo")` but it's actually 2 navigations and it's gonna be fast blink of this screen with cars list

so I'm looking for a solution where:

- user can go to cars list and just choose the car, then go to `finalInfo`
- user can go to cars list and then click "add" button, go through adding car process and from the last step of this process gonna be redirected to `finalInfo` but when he clicks back button on `finalInfo` it's gonna be acting like he just came from the cars list screen

Comment: Why not simply override the backButton behavior on android? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/

Comment: cause he can click back button twice. If my NewEmployeeStack process has more steps(and it has, cause above was only an example) i has to override backButtons in all screens in this process.

Comment: oh, then just manipulate your navigation stack before going to finalInfo, e.g. remove add car from stack when its an additional car so it looks like he went straight from cars list